# My scrip works fine in java class but same script fails when I use testng. It just opens the browser and fails my script

Tags: selenium, testng

Please Find the below code: I have performed the following steps, but didn't worked.
Please Help:

```
public class ForSe_TestCases        
public WebDriver driver;    

@BeforeTest     
public void setup ()    
{          
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path");
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();               
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();          
} 

@Test(priority = 0)     
public void Validlogin_IO () throws InterruptedException {
driver.navigate().to("http://**URL**"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("tengku.forse@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("Pass12345");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/button")).click();    
System.out.println("Login button pressed");
}
```

What can be the issue with TestNG ?

Comment: Please format your code, use a shorter and more concise title and add the description of the problem in the body of your post.

Comment: Thanks for editing my code. I didn't knew the correct formatting. Sorry for that. I used the same script in 'default package' and it works fine there. Created TestNG class and copied it in TestNG package. I'm new to this. Not sure if there's any mistake from my end. When I run the script in testng it opens the browser with URL 'data();' and immediately fails my test cases.

Comment: @Sanchit Are you still facing the issue or it got solved?

Comment: @dev its same. Still facing that issue. I have no idea why my script doesn't work in using TestNG annotations.

Comment: @Sanchit can you paste the exact error & update the question?

Comment: @Sanchit can you check with my updated solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try any/all of the following

1. Remove and Add TestNG jar again to ur project build path
2. UNinstall and reinstall the TestNG plugin
3. Clean the Eclipse project amd rerun.

If nothing works try this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { YOURCLASSNAME.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
}
```

In place of `YOURCLASSNAME` give the classname that contains the `@Test` annotations. This is like running your testing without the plugin from main method.

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, Nothing works. Problem is still same. When I run, TestNG opens the browser and immediately skip/fails Test. It says method requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the Test annotation.

Comment: I've created a new question for the same doubt. I explained the whole scenario in a detailed manner there, with proper code formatting and proper steps to produce. I request you all to please guide me there. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132924/selenium-script-fails-with-testng-annotation) @Xwris

Answer (score 0):

Update to Chrome driver 2.28, Google Chrome to 57.x and Selenium to 3.x.x  You also have to set the path of the Chrome driver before you open the browser.

```
package demo;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestAnyURL_TestNG 
{

    WebDriver driver;    

    @BeforeTest     
    public void setup ()    
    {          
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);               
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();          
    } 


    @Test(priority = 0)     
    public void Validlogin_IO () throws InterruptedException    
    {
    driver.navigate().to("http://google.com"); //ForSe test environment URL 
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("tengku.forse@gmail.com"); //this is official email 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("Pass12345"); //this is password 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/button")).click(); //click on submit button to login  
    System.out.println("Login button pressed");     }       //This code is to add new case  

    @Test (priority = 1)    
    public void AddCase() throws InterruptedException
    {          
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Add Case")); //To find 'Add Case' button on dashboard
    Actions action = new Actions (driver);      action.moveToElement(element); //Move mouse and hover to 'Add Case' button 
    action.click().build().perform(); //Click on 'Add Case' button 
    driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Perak Murder Case -53311");//Provide Case Name 
    driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSIImages\\FisheyeImages\\IMG_1187.JPG"+"\n"+"C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSIImages\\FisheyeImages\\IMG_1188.JPG"+"\n"+"C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSIImages\\FisheyeImages\\IMG_1189.JPG"+"\n"+"C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSIImages\\Fisheye Images\\IMG_1190.JPG");  //Upload files      
    driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload1")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSIImages\\EvidenceImages\\_DSC0970.JPG"+"\n"+"C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSI>Images\\EvidenceImages\\_DSC0971.JPG"+"\n"+"C:\\Users\\sanchit.IGENEDC\\Desktop\\iCSIImages\\Evidence Images\\_DSC0972.JPG");
    Thread.sleep(6000);         //wait for files to load        
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();//click on submit button     
   }
}
```

Check this code. This code successfully opens the google.co.in

Execute this file "Run As TestNG Test"

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for reply @Dev but the problem is still same. As explained by you, I've updated my selenium. Removed all old selenium jars and added the updated one. Updated chrome driver and java also. But this is also not helping me.

Comment: Is it a public IP? Can I access that?

Comment: No its private. Sorry you can't access it. Please refer this link. I've explained my question more specifically there. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132924/selenium-script-fails-with-testng-annotation)

Comment: @Sanchit Updated my Answer with test code. Replace `http://google.com` with your own `test URL`. Replace `package demo` by `your_package_name`. Replace `public class TestAnyURL_TestNG` with `public class your_class_name`.  Update me the status.

Comment: You are fabulous. Finally it's working for me with this code. Thank you so much. Can you explain what was wrong with my script. Was I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Sanchit, I think it fails because you are not waiting for the element to appear on the page and the webDriver (which is faster than its shadow!) thinks the first element you are trying to locate isn't there (id='email_address).

Try reading [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for implicit or explicit way to wait or use this code of mine below instead (if the element is present then the method returns true):

```
public boolean waitForElement(String elementXpath, int timeOut) {

    try{                    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut); 
    boolean elementPresent=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementXpath)).isDisplayed());

    System.out.printf("%nElement is present [T/F]..? ")+elementPresent;
    }        
    catch(TimeoutException e1){e1.printStackTrace();elementPresent=false;}          

    return elementPresent;   
 }
```

*Update after OP's comments*

To see if my method works, try replacing your first find element line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("tengku.forse@gmail.com"); //this is official email
```

with this code below instead (then your script won't break from then ownwards, if it does use this waiting method again for the 'breaking' element). I think your script is breaking straight away because you locate the element and sendKeys very fast without waiting for it to appear first!

```
waitForElement ("//*[@id='email_address']", 10);
if(elementPresent==true){
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("tengku.forse@gmail.com");
}
else{
System.out.println("FATAL! Couldn't locate email address field!");
}
```

Hope you can crack it this time round!

Comment: I'm already using implicit wait in `@BeforeTest` annotation and explicit wait in `@Test` annotation.

Comment: Don't use both! Try using only the waiting method above please

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check if it works for you now!

Comment: Hi. I've updated the code as mentioned by you. Sorry to say but the problem still exist. Actually it doesn't even invoke my URL.