# Selenium script fails with TestNG annotation

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Steps:
1. In eclipse I've created a new project named 'ForSe'.

2. Under 'src' folder → 'default package' I created a class named `Login.java`.
3. My code inside this class is like this:

   ```
   public class Login_Valid {      
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {                
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","*my path*");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.get("*URL of prject ForSe*");
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("*email address*");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("*Password*");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/button")).click();
       }
   }
   ```

**The scripts run very well when I run with `run as java application`.
But when I use the same script with TestNG, it skips/fails my test.**

Steps taken to create TestNG script is as follows:

1. Installed TestNG and under same `src` creates a new package named `ForSe_TestCases.java`
2. My TestNG scripts is as follows:

   ```
   public class ForSe_TestCases 
   {
       WebDriver driver;
       String url = "*project's URL*";

       @Test (priority = 0)
       public void IO_login(WebDriver driver) 
       {

           //ForSe test environment URL
           driver.navigate().to(url);

           //this is official email address of IO
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("*email address*");

           //this is password
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("*Password*");

           //click on submit button to login
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/button")).click();
           System.out.println("Login button pressed");
       }

       @BeforeTest
       public void setup() 
       {
           // Set property for Chrome
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","*my path*");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

           //apply implicit wait
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

           //maximize window
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
       }
   }
   ```

I'm unable to understand at which step I'm going wrong. This the error message I get on running my test by `Run as TestNG`

```
    [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException:
    Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [IO_login] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].

    ===============================================
    Default test
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
    ===============================================
    Default suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with setup of TestNG. Following code solved my problem:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", my_path);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change below line of your code.**

from `public void IO_login(WebDriver driver)` to `public void IO_login()`

Then try to run your code, it will surely work for you. For more details on this refer this below code.

```
public class ForSe_TestCases {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    String url = "http://google.com";

  @Test (priority = 0)
  public void IO_login() 
  {
       driver.navigate().to(url);
       System.out.println("Login Method");
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void setup()
  {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Tried but result is still same. It opens the browser will URL `data;()` and immediately fails.

Comment: When i execute above code on my end, it is working properly without showing any error. I guess in your case your chrome driver is getting corrupted. Download latest chrome driver from this site and then execute my code.  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/

Comment: I tried with latest chrome driver. Still doesn't work. I'm sure it's not chrome driver because the script works fine when I `run as java application`

Comment: Have you replaced my code properly? and which version you are using of selenium webdriver? chrome browser version? And please pass your error message.

Answer (score 0):

These can be a few of the issues:

1. "my path" is not a valid variable name. Change it to "my_path".
2. Define a `String my_path = "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe";` as a global variable.
3. Check the variable when you provide `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","my_path");`
4. Don't use `driver.manage().window().maximize();` instead handle it with Options Class.
5. `WebDriver driver` is defined globally at Class level, you don't have to pass it as an argument in `IO_login()`
6. Check this code:

   ```
   public class TestAnyURL_TestNG
   {
   WebDriver driver;
   String url = "http://google.com";
   String my_path = "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe";

   @Test (priority = 0)
   public void IO_login() 
   {

       //ForSe test environment URL
       driver.navigate().to(url);

       //this is official email address of IO
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("*email address*");

       //this is password
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("*Password*");

       //click on submit button to login
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/button")).click();
       System.out.println("Login button pressed");
   }

   @BeforeTest
   public void setup() 
   {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", my_path);
       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("test-type");
       options.addArguments("start-maximized");
       options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
       options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
       options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
       options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
       options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
       options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);        
   }
   }
   ```

Remember to:

1. Replace `http://google.com` with your `own_test_URL`.
2. Replace `package demo` by `package your_package_name`.
3. Replace `public class TestAnyURL_TestNG` with `public class your_class_name`
4. Run as "TestNG Test"
5. Update me the status.

Comment: Can you explain me why should i won't use `driver.manage().window().maximize();` I want to know the impacts, if i will use this line of code in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below and try, I tested it in my machine.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Testngtest 
{
WebDriver driver;
String url = "*project's URL*";

@Test (priority = 0)
public void IO_login() 
{

    //ForSe test environment URL
    driver.navigate().to("Url");

    //this is official email address of IO
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email_address']")).sendKeys("*email address*");

    //this is password
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("*Password*");

    //click on submit button to login
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/button")).click();
    System.out.println("Login button pressed");
}

@BeforeTest
public void setup() 
{
    // Set property for Chrome

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","*my path*");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //apply implicit wait
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //maximize window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
}
```

Below are the changes that I made to original code.

1.Removed driver parameter to IO_login method()

2.Removed declaration of web driver in setup method again, we already declared it inside the class and outside of all methods.

Let me know if you have any queries.